# Detect UWP app launch from UWP background task

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Is it possible to register for UWP app launch events from UWP background task? For example, once the UWP calc app is opened, my background task need to be notified on that.

Comment: Nope. Not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is possible.

Since Fall Creators Update (16299) there's new UWP App Diagnostics API through which you could enumerate all currently running processes. Not sure about registering for launch events, but if you periodically (for example every 5 seconds) enumerate running processes, you could get what you want.

Take a look at [this blogpost](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/), [this related GitHub sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/UWPTaskMonitor) and [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use [in-process background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task). These basically make it so the app basically goes in a lightweight mode when you exit the app and when you open it the app can handle all the processes with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can register and trigger a background task of trigger type Application trigger when App launches in the OnLaunched method.